# How to use and debug conditional statements in Python?

Tags: python

```
while True:

    n1 = int(input("Enter first number: "))
    if n1>255:
               print("Invalid input. Sorry the number should be less than 255.")
               continue
    elif n1<255:
               print("The input is valid.")


    n2 = int(input("Enter second number: "))
    if n2>255:
               print("Invalid input. Sorry the second number should be less than 255.")
               continue

    elif n2<255:
               print("The input is valid.")

    break
```

Whenever I enter 'n2' higher than 255, it shows enter first number. I want it to show enter second number.

[image]

Comment: you haven't figured out how to properly use `while`, `continue` and `break`. You can easily teach yourself that by playing with them a bit more.

Comment: Please change the title so that it describes your problem and don't use images.

Comment: This also might help you 
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `continue` statement in the first `if`. `continue` does not mean "go on". It means, "ignore the rest of the while/for loop, and repeat from its next iteration". So, actually, the next time you are at the input prompt, are not entering `n2`, you are again the the same line and entering `n1` again. Remove the `continue` statement.

Take a look at how `break` and `continue` statements work, they are pretty much the same in all languages (that I know of at least)

Comment: Do you mean "ignore the rest of the while/for loop **for this iteration**"? Your quoted text could be misunderstood otherwise - it sounds like you are describing a break out of the loop.

Comment: Right, I tried to make it as simple as possible, but it could be misunderstood. Edited

Answer (score 0):

`continue` starts the whole `while` loop over: it doesn't go back to before the last `if` statement or anything like that. So your second `continue` effectively starts your program over. You need to get rid of this `continue`, and use some other method to redo this input.